# about "play" action, is there anyway to simulate it without actually entering the canvas?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I successfully made it to send a score to facebook.

My question is there is any way to send the playing action.

When someone is entering into the canvas in web, the facebook sends a playing action

Can I do that with the iOS? maybe sending a 'play' action via post/get (how? never sent an action, and I cant find out how)

Thanks.
Amir.

Answer (score 0):

No, `games.playing` stories are automatic and created by Facebook based on canvas activity, there's no way to manually create them